# How to fix error 'This site can’t be reached. Took too long to respond' for a service on an Ubuntu server?

Tags: networking, 16.04, server, localhost

How to fix error 'This site can’t be reached. Took too long to respond' for a service on an Ubuntu server?

```
ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT
```

I SSH into a remote Ubuntu virtual machine and I want to open http://IPaddress:8081/#/ in a browser outside of the Ubuntu Server.

Ping and tracert returned:

```
Request timed out.
```

Comment: Do you really want to publicly post your IP address?

Comment: @android-dev Is my edit sufficient?

Comment: Yes, although it is still visible in the edit history. If you'd like, I'll ask a moderator to nuke the old revision.

Comment: Okay, I've asked them to redact revision one.

Comment: Since the ping fails: Could it be that you are trying to reach an IPv4-address on a DSLite-type connection?

Answer (score 1):

Many Chrome users facing this issue - "cant reach website" with the message showing "Unexpectedly closed the connection" or "Server DNS address could not be found" "ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED" and took too long to respond..

The reason of the error causing some websites not loading is because of DNS lookup failed - I was also got stuck here, and then I found this tutorial showing server DNS address could not be found fix.

http://www.problogbooster.com/2015/03/fix-this-site-cannot-be-reached-err-connection-timed-out-reset-chrome-windows-error-dns-address-not-found-lookup-failure-localhost-refused-to-connect-solved.html

I got the solution by resetting, you may find something else check it

Answer (score 0):

For me, I got it working by clearing the cache of the browser and adding a dns server to dhcp configuration:

`$ sudo vim /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

In the last line add a line (press <kbd>i</kbd> for insert, and <kbd>esc</kbd> to leave insert mode, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ZZ</kbd> to leave vim with changes saved):

`supersede domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;`

Afterwards restart the service:

`sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service`